# any one line code to remove single value from Shared Preference?

Tags: android

Is there any one line code to remove a value or index from shared preference.
something like: SharedPreference.remove("FILENAME", value)

Comment: Did you even look at the docs?! - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Comment: @David, yes I did, but I cant find any function which deletes a value from PREFILE, remove command completely removes the file not value, If you know any command for it, pls share with us\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for one line solution you could use something like this

```
SharedPreference sp;
// initialize it
sp.edit().remove("value_key").commit();
```

But i don't see any point of using it like this unless you wan't to make your colleagues life harder while reading it.